# Any Angular tools to visualise a project (large scale project )?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering if I could receive some advice on visually representing a system built in VS with angular code controlling the font end.

I would ideally like to find something that can produce something similar to project dependency graph we find through VS ultimate tool or NDepend.

I know of quite a few .NET code and project visualisation tools, but am having a real struggle finding a suitable one for Angular JS

Is this a potential community project right here? Anyone want to collaborate on the/an approach as I believe this will help both existing developers and new developers to further grasp Angular and how it traverses systems on both the smaller and larger scales.

I would love to hear how others might have visually represented code dependencies in angular.

So.
To conclude - Are there any existing tools to visualise angular dependencies in a project environment or does anyone want to collaborate to create one?
Thanks for reading and hope this finds everyone well and in good health.
Gruffy :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the AngularJS Graph chrome extension : http://angularjs-graph.org/

My experience was that it "worked" out of the box, as in the visualisation rendered without any configuration on OSX. I am still coming to grips with how practically useful it is, but it certainly looks cool.

Comment: which version of angular is this for? I dont see any such details wether it is for Angular 1 or 2+ .

Comment: Generally "angularjs" refers to 1.X whereas "angular" refers to 2+ . This is not universally followed, but in my experience is a pretty good indicator. Also a look at the github project reveals it is Angular 1.X as there are open tickets requesting Angular 2.0 support

Answer (score 1):

The [Chrome extension Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang-stable/niopocochgahfkiccpjmmpchncjoapek?hl=en) has some useful visualisers for angular development, including, among others, a service dependency tree.

Comment: Hey dolt, thanks for the advice, oddly enough I have already loaded Batarang - This however, is not the droid i`m looking for!
Ultimately, I wanted a way of generating a dependency graph of sorts and other graphical high level architecture overviews.
Thank you for your contribution though, and batarang is pretty cool i have to admit from a dev end of things.

Comment: Batarang **does** have a visual service dependency graph (see the dependencies tab!), and a tool for visualizing scope nesting structure, albeit neither of them is customizable.

Comment: Thanks again dolt, indeed batarang is a wonderful tool.  and yes, the dependencies and scope visualizer is pretty cool too. I will mark the answer tomorrow if there are no further tools outside of batarang that can help visualise Angular :)

Comment: Dead link, github page of project is archived. I don't think this is a thing anymore.